# How to change the StatusBar color of the splash screen?

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I'm using React Native for building my android application and I've followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae) to set up my splash screen. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdks5.gif). My main problem is that the status bar color changes to black, I can't solve this by having `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>` in my `styles.xml` file, and `<color name="blue">#009CD7</color>`, `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#009CD7</color>` in my `colors.xml` file.

Bonus question: how to center the image without hardcoding a margin so that it stays in the center regardless of the device the app is running on?

Comment: add this line to your style : 
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/your_color</item>

Comment: @AslamHossin Unfortunately, nothing's changed

Comment: Is it your theme is MaterialTheme then it will works?

Comment: You have put the above line in v21/style.xml  status bar color changed introduced after API level 21.

Answer (score 15):

Add `colorPrimaryDark` one more item in your current splash theme or create a new one.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then use it as a second parameter while showing SplashScreen.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme, true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a third argument to show function as true

Answer (score 4):

If you see an error something like that -> "int can not be boolean"
Just add third parameter to MainActivity.java

```
SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme, true);
```

Comment: This worked, in my case, i had to modify it to,

```SplashScreen.show(this,R.style.SplashScreenTheme, true);```

Comment: bro can you share the complete code to change the background color of the status bar in React native splash screen

Answer (score 1):

Create a style definition for this in android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
         <style name="SplashTheme" parent="SplashScreen_SplashTheme">
             <item name="colorPrimaryDark">your_color</item>
         </style>
   </resources>
```

now you have change **show** method to include your custom style:

```
SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme);
```

you are donw now :)

Answer (score 1):

After a headache finally found the answer and it was mentioned in the package documentations . This will change the background color of status bar and bottom navigation  of mobiles and this is whats required after making configs of splash screen . The steps are

Add this code to `app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml` file  in android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="status_bar_color">#E12027</color> // your desired color
</resources>
```

Add this code to `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` file  in android

```
  <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="SplashScreen_SplashTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
    </style>
```

and finally chnage  this piece of code from this in MainActivity.java file

`SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme);`

to

`SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme,true);`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the TaskBar color, just add the activity and the color that you desire in the output function.

```
fun setTaskBarColored(colored: Int,activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window!!.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window!!.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, colored)
        }
    }
```

And also the same applies for the NavigationBar

```
    fun setNavigationBarColored(colored: Int, activity: Activity){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity.window!!.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity.window!!.navigationBarColor =  ContextCompat.getColor(activity, colored)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I add those 'activities'? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add this JSX code to the root of your app instead of editing any native files.

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
```

Also in order to center your image, wrap it with a view and add the styling “{justifyContent: ‘center’, alignItems: ‘center’}”.  If that doesn’t work then add this style directly to your image component “alignSelf: ‘center’”

Comment: during splash screen i got gray color and only when my navigation ready to show it changes to color i picked